# sencha generate app doesn't work

Tags: sencha-touch

I downloaded [sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/)

and extracted into a folder.

And then I downloaded [the sdk tool](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download)

and installed it.

Used windows 7 cmd, **cd** to the sencha touch folder, and then run **sencha generate app myapp ../myapp**,
then it shows a red error message "The current working directory is not a valid SDK directory. Please 'cd' into a SDK directory before executing this command."

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Sencha SDK 2.1.0, you have to use the Sencha CMD instead of Sencha SDK Tools.

Here is the system setup documentation for Sencha CMD: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command